# Foreignkey filtering spanning across multiple models

Tags: django

I have following four models and a form defined in forms.py. There is a model (CodeVillage) that lists some villages. Model CodePlaces lists a number of places around each village. Model Households contains some details of households living in villages. Model occupations has records for various members of households and their occupations.

The occupations_form is used as an inline in admin form for households. I would like the work_place foreignkey in the form filtered so that it shows only places around the village in which a particular household lives. I am unable to figure out how to correctly get the queryset that will pick village from related record in household model, and then pick places from the related record in codeplaces model.

Would really appreciate any help in fixing this filter.

models.py

```
class CodeVillage(models.Model):
    village_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.village_name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.village_name


class CodePlaces(models.Model):
    village =  models.ForeignKey(CodeVillage, blank=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("location","place"),)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.location, self.place)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.location, self.place)

class Household(models.Model):
    village =  models.ForeignKey(CodeVillage, blank=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    household_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    head_of_household = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

class occupations(models.Model):
    sno = models.ForeignKey(Household,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    work_place  = models.ForeignKey(CodePlaces, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("sno", "person_number","occupation"),)
```

forms.py

```
class occupations_form(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super (occupations_form,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['work_place'].queryset = CodePlaces.objects.filter(village=occupations__household.instance.village_id)
    class Meta:
        model = occupations
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
self.fields['work_place'].queryset = CodePlaces.objects.filter(village__household__id=self.instance.sno_id)
```